# What is DataBaseReader.Item equivalent in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, vb.net-2010

How can we use this vb code and convert it in c#

```
Dim reader As OracleDataReader
If Not reader.Item("ABC") Is DBNull.Value
```

There is no Item in c#, i tried GetSchemaTable().Columns.Cointains("ABC") but that is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason the IDataReader in C# doesn't have an Item `property` like in VB.NET. 
You could use

```
var value = (reader["ABC"] as String)??String.Empty;
```

though. That should work with DBNull as well.